# Rendering of a graph using dot program

Tags: graphviz

I am trying to display a graph with the `dot` program with an example taken from https://graphs.grevian.org/example#example-2 .
I should get this output:

[image]

Instead I get this one.

[image]

How is it possible to generate the second one?

Here is the code I used:

```
dot graph_path.dot -Tpdf > vis.pdf
```

```
graph {
    a -- b;
    b -- c;
    c -- d;
    d -- e;
    e -- f;
    a -- f;
    a -- c;
    a -- d;
    a -- e;
    b -- d;
    b -- e;
    b -- f;
    c -- e;
    c -- f;
    d -- f;
}
```

**Edit**
In the man page of dot in my terminal (under MacOS 11.6.1), the following is written:

```
...
OUTPUT FORMATS
       Graphviz uses an extensible plugin mechanism for its output renderers, so  to  see  what  output  formats  your
       installation of dot supports you can use ``dot -T:'' and check the warning message.  Also, The plugin mechanism
       supports multiple implementations of the output formats, allowing variations in the renderers  and  formatters.
       To  see  what  variants  are  available for a particular output format, use, for example: ``dot -Tpng:'' and to
       force a particular variant, use, for example: ``dot -Tpng:gd''
...
```

So I assume that `Graphviz` is used

**EDIT 2**

thanks to the answer of sroush, there are several commands to create graphs such as:

```
dot graphK6.dot -Tpdf > vis1.pdf
sfdp graphK6.dot -Tpdf > vis2.pdf 
neato graphK6.dot -Tpdf > vis3.pdf
circo graphK6.dot -Tpdf > vis4.pdf
```

Comment: Are you using graphviz, or something else?

Comment: @ravenspoint I am using dot as the command line indicates ‘dot graph_path.dot -Tpdf > vis.pdf ‘

Comment: @ravenspoint. I edited the question. It seems that Graphviz is indeed used

Comment: Good.  Have you read the graphviz documentation?  It contains detailed information on the layout parameters and numerous examples of how to achieve different effects.  Once you have done so, and are still stuck, then you should edit your question to tell us what you tried. ( Your question shows absolutely no effort to try adjusting the layout parameters )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, this is a Graphviz result, but it was not produced by the **dot** layout engine.  It was produced by the **circo** layout engine.
Graphviz has 6 primary engines (and more related programs) that all take the same input language.
Circo is not well documented, but here is the common "man" page.   (http://www.graphviz.org/pdf/dot.1.pdf)
Here is the same input run through the 6 primary engines:
[image]